# Fetching the data of the dialog box and sending it to the server in Kendoui?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I send the information of the dialogue box (popup editing in kendogrid) to the server?

I've written the code, but I don't know what I should write in the data part.

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/E9CbR/1/embedded/result/)

```
      save: function (e) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'api/apdevice',
                    type: 'POST',
                    datatype: 'application/json',
                    data: {
                        //I don't know what I should write in the data part.
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('yes ' + data);
                    },

                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('no ' + data);
                    }

                });
            }
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kendo UI Grid, `save` receives the data as argument in `model`.

So your code should be something like:

```
save: function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/apdevice',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'application/json',
        data: e.model,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('yes ' + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('no ' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When I click on the update button and I firebug an error is displayed TypeError: e is undefined

Comment: `e` is the argument to `save` handler function. Did you include it? Do you mind trying to add an `alert("e: " + e);`. It should popup an `alert` saying something like: "e: [Object object]`

Comment: I'm currently a Message Alert: "Yes" or "No"

Comment: But that `e` is a different `e`, not the one in the `save` function. You should check the call stack and see inside your code what is causing that error.

Comment: I changed my code to this and now does not error <pre> data: {
                            json:JSON.stringify(e.model),
                        },<code>

Comment: You said to _this_ but I think that the link or the "this" is actually missing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

save: function (e) {

```
     var jsonData = {
                    your_property:$(.yourinput).val(),
                    your_property1:$(.yourinput).val(),
                    your_property2:$(.yourinput).val()
            }

            $.ajax({

                url: 'api/apdevice',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('yes ' + data);
                },

                error: function (data) {
                    alert('no ' + data);
                }

            });
        }
```